# Request fail when connection to IBGE API

Tags: request

I am trying to make an request on IBGE API and for some reason it came up with that error

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='servicodados.ibge.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/agregados/5938/periodos/2014%7C2015%7C2016%7C2017%7C2018%7C2019%7C2020/variaveis/37%7C553%7C552%7C497%7C530%7C496%7C543%7C571%7C570%7C545%7C551%7C544%7C498%7C555%7C549%7C522%7C525%7C528%7C563%7C562%7C527%7C550%7C526?localidades=N6%5Ball%5D (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(136, '[X509: NO_CERTIFICATE_OR_CRL_FOUND] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4149)')))

I have no idea why is no connection with the API